# Distribution of trivial subset sums

Tags: pr.probability, computer-science, additive-combinatorics

Suppose I have a set $S$ of $n$ integers picked independently, uniformly at random from $[-L, L].$ Let $z(S)$ be the number of subsets of $S$ which sum to zero. The question is: what is the distributon of the variable $z(S)$ (I am interested in $n$ fixed and $L$ growing)?

Comment: To be clear, you pick $S$ uniformly at random from all size-$n$ subsets of $\{-L, \dots, L\}$, right? (As opposed to picking $n$ integers independently and uniformly at random from $\{-L,\dots,L\}$.)

Comment: @usul No, actually I mean the entries are picked uniformly, independently, at random (as in your second option).

Comment: @usul modified to clarify...

Comment: So the "subsets" are really subsets of indices, not of $S$? Example: If $S: -1,-1,1,1$, then $z(S)=5$?

Comment: If you add $L+1$ to the interval, then you're looking at the number of ways to sum to $L+1$ from $[1,L]$. You necessarily need all your chosen numbers to be less than $L-1$, which occurs with probability $\binom{L-1}{n}$, after which you are evaluating $p(L-1)$: the number of partitions of $L-1$ with distinct parts, which equals the number of partitions with odd parts by Euler's theorem. I'm guessing the growth rate is known via circle methods or other analytic combinatorics, probably something like $O(\exp(c\sqrt{n})/n)$.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be $2^n/(L\sqrt{n})$? If the integers you pick are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, then for each $A\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $x_A=\sum_{i\in A}x_i$. I would expect it to be the case that the $x_A$ for distinct $A$ are independent. Most $A$'s have around $n/2$ elements, so that most $x_A$'s have distribution something like $N(0,L\sqrt n)$. The probability that each one is 0 is therefore something like $1/(L\sqrt n)$. So that I would expect that $\mathbb Ez(S)\approx 2^n/(L\sqrt n)$.

Comment: @Anthony Quas: I don't think the $x_A$ can be (even approximately) independent, I would expect them to be highly correlated if the two sets have appreciable overlap.

Comment: @AlexR I am not sure what you are talking about...

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, your first comment is correct.

Comment: So I guess my argument doesn't rely on independence: by linearity of expectation one has $\mathbb E z(S)=\sum_A \mathbb P(x_A=0)$.